# How to correctly parse an XML document with arbitrary namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces

I am trying to parse somewhat standard XML documents that use a schema called [MARCXML](http://www.loc.gov/standards/marcxml/) from various sources.

Here are the first few lines of an example XML file that needs to be handled...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<marc:collection xmlns:marc="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim http://www.loc.gov/standards/marcxml/schema/MARC21slim.xsd">
  <marc:record>
    <marc:leader>00925njm  22002777a 4500</marc:leader>
```

and one without namespace prefixes...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<collection xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim">
  <record>
    <leader>01142cam  2200301 a 4500</leader>
```

**Key point:** in order to get the XPaths to resolve further along in the program I have to go through a regex routine to add the namespaces to the NameTable (which doesn't add them by default). This seems unnecessary to me.

```
Regex xmlNamespace = new Regex("xmlns:(?<PREFIX>[^=]+)=\"(?<URI>[^\"]+)\"", RegexOptions.Compiled);

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlRecord);
XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);

MatchCollection namespaces = xmlNamespace.Matches(xmlRecord);
foreach (Match n in namespaces)
{
    nsMgr.AddNamespace(n.Groups["PREFIX"].ToString(), n.Groups["URI"].ToString());
}
```

The XPath call looks something like this...

`XmlNode leaderNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(".//" + LeaderNode, nsMgr);`

Where `LeaderNode` is a configurable value and would equal `"marc:leader"` in the first example and `"leader"` in the second example.

Is there a better, more efficient way to do  this? Note: suggestions for solving this using LINQ are welcome, but I would mainly like to know how to solve this using `XmlDocument`.

**EDIT:** I took GrayWizardx's advice and now have the following code...

```
if (LeaderNode.Contains(":"))
{
    string prefix = LeaderNode.Substring(0, LeaderNode.IndexOf(':'));
    XmlNode root = xmlDoc.FirstChild;
    string nameSpace = root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix(prefix);
    nsMgr.AddNamespace(prefix, nameSpace);
}
```

Now there's no more dependency on Regex!

Comment: I am facing almost the exact same problem. How do you accomplish your `LeaderNode` magic? Do you have precognition of what record type you're dealing with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *know* there is going to be a given element in the document (for instance the root element) you could try using [GetNamespaceOfPrefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.getnamespaceofprefix.aspx).

Comment: This looks promising. I'll give it a try :)

Comment: The way I understand namespaces, they can be declared anywhere in the document. Can you abstract this method enough to deal with that general case?

Comment: @Patrick M I am not sure to be honest. My understanding was that they had to be defined on the root element of the document, but the probably could be added to any parent element. I havent looked at this for a while.